# Angular service syntax

Tags: angular

I'm trying to post certain data to the backend of my application (node.js and mysql) to send an email with this data.

I want to include two objects (account and labSwap) in this post method, what is the correct syntax/way to do this?

Thank you.

account.service.ts:

```
    notifyLecturer(account: Account, labSwap: LabSwap) {
        return this.http.post(`${baseUrl}/notifyLecturer`, account) , this.http.post(`${baseUrl}/notifyLecturer`, labSwap);
        // or &&?
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you are after??

```
notifyLecturer(account: Account, labSwap: LabSwap) {
    return this.http.post(`${baseUrl}/notifyLecturer`,  {account,labSwap})
}
```

payload will be like

```
{
  account:{accountJsonContent}, labSwap:{labswapJsonContent}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. It is exactly what I am after.

In my code to call the function to trigger this functionality, can I add a second object like this:

"this.accountService.notifyLecturer(this.account, this.labSwap)" ?

Otherwise email recipient is not defined.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes I guess, you should be doing this.